Confusion between GHCup and Cabal as regards versions of installed packages (system-wise and in specific cabal projects)
This is what I see when I run ghcup tui in a terminal in $HOME:
┌──────────────────────────────────GHCup──────────────────────────────────┐
│    Tool  Version         Tags                          Notes            │
│─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────│
│✔✔  GHCup 0.1.30.0   latest,recommended                                  │
│─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────│
│✗   Stack 2.15.7     latest                                              │
│✗   Stack 2.15.5     recommended                                         │
│✗   Stack 2.15.3                                                         │
│─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────│
│✗   HLS   2.9.0.1    latest                                              │
│✗   HLS   2.9.0.0                                                        │
│✗   HLS   2.8.0.0                                                        │
│✔✔  HLS   2.7.0.0    recommended                                         │
│✗   HLS   2.6.0.0                                                        │
│─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────│
│✗   cabal 3.12.1.0   latest                                              │
│✔✔  cabal 3.10.3.0   recommended                                         │
│✗   cabal 3.6.2.0-p1                                                     │
│─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────│
│✗   GHC   9.10.1     latest,base-4.20.0.0                                │
│✔   GHC   9.8.2      base-4.19.1.0                 hls-powered,2024-02-23│
│✗   GHC   9.6.6      base-4.18.2.1                                       │
│✗   GHC   9.6.5      base-4.18.2.1                                       │
│✔✔  GHC   9.4.8      recommended,base-4.17.2.1     hls-powered           │
│✗   GHC   9.2.8      base-4.16.4.0                 hls-powered           │
│✗   GHC   9.0.2      base-4.15.1.0                                       │
│✗   GHC   8.10.7     base-4.14.3.0                                       │
│✗   GHC   8.8.4      base-4.13.0.0                                       │
│✗   GHC   8.6.5      base-4.12.0.0                                       │
│✗   GHC   8.4.4      base-4.11.1.0                                       │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

If I enter cabal info ghc | grep -i installed in that terminal, I get
    Versions installed: 9.4.8

If I set the other installed GHC from ghcup tui, and rerun the same command, I get
    Versions installed: 9.8.2

meaning that cabal info ghc is reflecting what version of GHC I have set via GHCup.
But then if I enter
cabal info hls | grep -i installed:

I get
    Versions installed: [ Not installed ]

which is clearly in contrast with what I see in the screen above, that tells me HLS 2.7.0.0 is installed and set.
Similarly, if I do
cabal info cabal | grep -i installed:

I get
    Versions installed: [ Not installed ]

But running that without grepping anything showed this:
* cabal            (library)
    Synopsis:      placeholder for Cabal package, you want the upper case Cabal
    Versions available: 0.0.0.0
    Versions installed: [ Not installed ]
    Homepage:      [ Not specified ]
    Bug reports:   [ Not specified ]
    Category:      Development
    License:       BSD2
    Author:        Carter Tazio Schonwald
    Maintainer:    carter.schonwald@gmail.com
    Source repo:   [ Not specified ]
    Dependencies:  youProbablyWantCapitalCabal <0 && >1, base <300
    Cached:        No
    Modules:

so I tried
cabal info Cabal | grep -i installed:

which resulted in
    Versions installed: 3.10.2.0

which is also in contrast with what I see in the screen above, that says I have Cabal 3.10.3.0, not 3.10.2.0.
Can anybody help me understand what these conflicting informations mean?

Besides, even though I use dbus for this project, the command
cabal info dbus | grep -i installed:

results in
    Versions installed: [ Not installed ]

But I think this is normal because dbus is not installed "system-wise" but only in that directly where I've cloned the repo and built the project in? Am I correct? In which case, how would I use cabal info to ask info "in the current directory", if the question even makes sense?

The cabal info command tells you what haskell packages are installed. so it tells you ghc as a haskell package (accessible to be imported and linked against) is installed, but not the cabal or hls haskell packages. This is accurate!
The things you have installed with ghcup are for the most part not haskell packages but executable binaries, and there's no reason ghcup would know about them.
As to your final question and speculation, yes cabal info only talks about the ghc package database installs not installs into the package-level storedir. So you can't use it to ask info "in the current directory" at all.

but not the cabal or hls haskell packages, why? Aren't those packages installed?

no, those packages are not installed! the binary executables are, but the packages (as haskell libraries) aren't. that's why they don't show up.

Here are some disconnected, but relevant, facts:

There are Haskell packages named ghc, cabal, Cabal, cabal-install, hls, and haskell-language-server.
Haskell packages may contain executables, libraries, or both.
There are executables named ghc, cabal, and haskell-language-server.
Each version of GHC has its own independent package database.
Cabal has a global collection of packages called a "store" to differentiate it from a GHC-style package database.
Individual cabal projects can also have local collections of packages. I'm not sure there's a codified name for these; I'll call it a "local store" in this answer.

Now let's talk about what information your various commands showed you.
% ghcup tui
│✔✔  cabal 3.10.3.0   recommended
│✔✔  HLS   2.7.0.0    recommended
│✔   GHC   9.8.2      base-4.19.1.0                 hls-powered,2024-02-23
│✔✔  GHC   9.4.8      recommended,base-4.17.2.1     hls-powered

This is showing you information about executables that ghcup has made available to you. A single check mark indicates that a versioned name of the executable is available, e.g. cabal-3.10.3.0 or ghc-9.8.2. (The versioning info for haskell-language-server is a bit more complicated. You might have, for example, an executable named haskell-language-server-9.8.2~2.7.0.0.) A double check mark indicates which version the non-versioned name means; e.g. both ghc-9.8.2 and ghc-9.4.8 are available, and just plain ghc means ghc-9.4.8 in the setup described above.
Some of these executables may be ones that you can install by building and installing a Haskell package through cabal. For example, one way to acquire a cabal executable is to run cabal install cabal-install. However, the executables made available to you through ghcup are not acquired in this way; rather, they are downloaded as pre-built binaries, and potentially installed in a different location than where cabal would put them.
% cabal info ghc | grep -i installed
Versions installed: 9.4.8

This cabal info command will tell you about libraries installed into the default GHC's package database. Because the non-versioned name ghc currently points to ghc-9.4.8, this cabal info query is asking GHC 9.4.8 about its package database. The GHC compiler ships with a library named ghc in its package database, and its version is the one printed here -- the GHC maintainers by convention choose the same version number for the GHC compiler and the ghc library it ships with.

If I set the other installed GHC from ghcup tui, and rerun the same command, cabal info ghc is reflecting what version of GHC I have set via GHCup.

Sort of, yes. See above. It is in fact reflecting what version of the ghc library is available to the GHC compiler you have set.
% cabal info hls | grep -i installed
Versions installed: [ Not installed ]

This is not asking about the HLS you think it's asking about. There is an hls package on Hackage, but it is not the Haskell language server. That package is named haskell-language-server.
Additionally, this is asking GHC's package database about the library associated with that package, but the way you acquired the server did not involve building and installing its library; you got a pre-built binary. So even if you corrected the query, you almost certainly would not see any versions installed.
% cabal info Cabal | grep -i installed
Versions installed: 3.10.2.0

Again, this is telling you the version of the Cabal library installed in the current GHC's package database. There's three problems with comparing that to the version listed by ghcup:

The Cabal package does not provide the cabal executable; the cabal executable comes from the cabal-install package.
You did not acquire the cabal executable by building and installing the cabal-install package.
GHC's package database only knows about libraries anyway, not executables.


How would I use cabal info to ask info "in the current directory", if the question even makes sense?

You can look at a file named plan.json buried somewhere inside the dist-newstyle directory of a cabal project to learn about the local store and the current project's interaction with the global store. It's a bit complicated though, so you probably want a bit more tooling. I believe the plan has always been for cabal to ship with some way to query this information. I don't know if that feature has landed yet or not, but you can use cabal-plan, which is a prototype of some of the relevant functionality.

Wait, is hls this?!

one way to acquire a cabal executable is to run cabal install cabal-install What? So isn't cabal in cabal install cabal-install the very executable I'm trying to install??? I'm confused.

@Enlico That is one way to acquire a cabal executable -- that has, as a prerequisite, already having a cabal executable. Nothing contradictory there! There's lots of other programs with that property -- e.g. wget can be used to acquire a wget executable, ghc + the GHC source can be used to acquire a ghc executable, apt can be used to get an apt executable, etc.

Can you please clarify? Why would I run cabal install cabal-install to get cabal if I have it in the first place? Same question for all the others examples. Assume there's no such a thing as a ghc/wget executable on a freshly installed linux distro; how is the shell gonna do anything sensible with a command line starting with ghc/wget?

Another point I don't find clear: but the way you acquired the server did not involve building and installing its library. How do you know how I acquired the server? I think I installed via ghcup tui, but is that something you deduce from just ✔✔  HLS   2.7.0.0? Would that not be there even if I had installed HLS another way?

@Enlico "Why would I run cabal to get cabal?" For example, to install a different version, or to begin debugging/modifying the tool, or to make the tool available from a different path for some chroot or something. Same answer for other examples. "On a freshly installed linux distro, how is the shell gonna do anything sensible?" It isn't. "How do you know how I acquired the server?" Because your ghcup output says how -- so yes, deduced from ✔✔  HLS   2.7.0.0, which would not appear in that way if you had installed HLS in another way.

@Enlico I guess, strictly speaking, I do not know that you did not acquire the server in another way. But I do know that one of the ways you acquired the server is through ghcup, and I'm making an assumption that if you had tried to get it through other means you would have said something about that.
